# Installing turtlebot software on beagleboard

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, turtlebot, beagleboard

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello I am trying to install turtlebot software on beagleboard so that i can use beagleboard rather then Laptop in turtlebot, its just a try to implement FASTSLAM1.0, I installed ubuntu and ROS on beagleboard from source, Is there any way to install Turtlebot from source.
The particular error is:

> > W: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/natty/Release  Unable to find >>expected entry 'main/binary-armel/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or >>malformed file)

> > E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Is it good practise to use beagleboard on turtlebot instead of a high power and high processing laptop for implementing FASTSLAM1.0?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10435/installing-turtlebot-software-on-beagleboard./) by [sunilsulania9192](https://answers.ros.org/users/748/sunilsulania9192/) on ROS Answers with karma: 224 on 2011-06-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

#Installing ROS Diamondback turtlebot-robot variant on BeagleBoard xM running Ubuntu 11.04 from Source
This is a work in progress and is only meant to supplement the existing TurtleBot tutorials.

### Install Ubuntu packages on BeagleBoard xM

sudo apt-get install build-essential python-yaml cmake subversion wget python-setuptools mercurial

### Install rosinstall

sudo easy_install -U rosinstall

### Install ROS diamondback variant turtlebot-robot:

rosinstall ~/ros "http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=diamondback&variant=turtlebot-robot&overlay=no"

### Set up your environment.

echo "source ~/ros/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc

### Use rosmake to build the various ROS and TurtleBot packages:

I am still working on the best way the make all the necessary packages.

### You may want to install the following Ubuntu packages in advance:

sudo apt-get install python-serial libglut3-dev libcppunit-dev graphviz libxext-dev python-sip-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev unzip libxml2-dev python-wxgtk2.8 libqhull-dev libhdf5-serial-dev joystick libusb-1.0-0-dev flex autoconf libusb-dev automake bluez bison python-bluez libgtk2.0-dev libbluetooth-dev

### Missing packages from Ubuntu natty arm repositories:

The openni-dev, ps-engine (I'm sure that there are others) packages are not currently available from Ubuntu natty arm repositories. Without these packages the Kinect does not work but you can drive the TurtleBot around using the keyboard or joystick.

---

Originally posted by [JamesRonald](https://answers.ros.org/users/594/jamesronald/) with karma: 81 on 2011-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [domikilo](https://answers.ros.org/users/8836/domikilo/) on 2013-11-14**:
Can I do it with Ubuntu 13.04 on beagleboard, and If I can , Is it support get image form kinect camera in turtlebot

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

WillowGarage is not building ARM debian packages, so you will have to install from [source](http://www.ros.org/wiki/diamondback/Installation/Ubuntu/Source).

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-06-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JamesRonald](https://answers.ros.org/users/594/jamesronald/) on 2011-07-04**:
Brian, I'm still very interested. Which packages (openni-dev, ps-engine, nite-dev, turtlebot-robot and dependencies?  Let me know if I can help.

**Comment by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) on 2011-07-01**:
We are working on binary ARM packages; stay tuned...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While installing from

rosinstall ~/ros "http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=diamondback&variant=turtlebot-robot&overlay=no"

I got this error :

Installing http://svn.pointclouds.org/ros/tags/perception_pcl-0.10.0  to /home/turtlebot/ros/perception_pcl

svn: OPTIONS of 'http://svn.pointclouds.org/ros/tags/perception_pcl-0.10.0': Could not read

status line: Connection reset by peer (http://svn.pointclouds.org)

ERROR: Failed to install tree '/home/turtlebot/ros/perception_pcl'
vcs not setup correctly

turtlebot@omap:~$ svn: Caught signal

Suggest some solution

---

Originally posted by [sunilsulania9192](https://answers.ros.org/users/748/sunilsulania9192/) with karma: 224 on 2011-07-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sunilsulania9192](https://answers.ros.org/users/748/sunilsulania9192/) on 2011-07-04**:
woowww!!! Its like start installing in the morning and forget it untill evening, took more then 4 hours to completely install turtlebot software. :)

**Comment by [JamesRonald](https://answers.ros.org/users/594/jamesronald/) on 2011-07-04**:
That's strange. Perhaps the SVN repository was not available when you tried.   The SVN repository seems fine now.   I would just try deleting and running rosinstall again.